# Убрать рамку с groupbox c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Надо полностью убрать рамку с groupbox. Чтоб остались только элементы внутри.

Comment: Возьмите `Panel` вместо `GroupBox`.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что исчерпывающий ответ уже есть, просто он не принят.

Comment: @Andrew это вообще не повод закрывать вопросы. Дух поднимает те вопросы, в которых нет ответов с рейтингом хотя бы 1. Достаточно просто плюсануть ответ.

Comment: @Andrew можете дать ссылку, где именно? (Upd, ок если нет). Вообще вопросы стоит закрывать только если для ответа нужна правка от автора (именно от автора, доп инфа, например), или если вопрос - оффтопик. Вот тема на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/177221

Comment: @PashaPash нужно искать по истории браузера за несколько недель... на 2х компьютерах... я не помню как тема называлась - я на нее тогда нечаянно набрел =( Если очень нужно - поищу. Но чесно -- этим заниматся влом.Если отпишешь что оч нужно - завтра выделю время и найду

Answer (score 4):

Убрать границы самого `GroupBox` нельзя. Как альтернативу используйте [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx). Принципиальной разницы между ними нет, сама `Panel` может сливаться с основной формой. Если нужно больше информации [тут хорошо описаны все варианты](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/3.2.php).